# WebSockets and Heroku: pushing data to the user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, websocket

I am build a real time web application using Ruby on Rails and Heroku seems to be the best option for hosting it.

I would prefer pushing new data to the user, when it becomes available, instead of pulling it by sending AJAX requests every few seconds.

[Pusher](http://pusher.com/) seems to be suggested by Heroku for a such kind of job, but it has some limitations, brings additional costs, and makes you dependent on an external API.

Is there any other option to use WebSockets on Heroku?

Comment: I use a service called pubnub which was really easy to integrate, really depends on the data you are sending though.  http://pubnub.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna do websockets you need to use a different server besides rails. And since your on heroku you don't have the flexibility.

Optionally you can host a websockets enabled node server on an ec2 micro instance. Then in your rails app when you want to push -- do a request to the node server and the it will go to the clients.

Comment: This is now possible on heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout#longpolling_and_streaming_responses

Comment: @BrianArmstrong what does that have to do w/ web sockets?

Comment: If you want to be able to push content to clients, it doesn't necessarily have to be over websockets. Most websocket libraries like socket.io are capable of falling back to long-polling strategies. Heroku doesn't support WebSockets, but you can configure socket.io to not use web sockets and get the same sort of pushing-data-to-clients experience OP is looking for without running a separate server.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need one way communication try using Server Side events.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options that you can use with Heroku aside from Pusher:

1) Like Eric Fode mentioned above, you could use SSE given you don't need two-way communication. There is a Heroku add-on which you could leverage for this: https://addons.heroku.com/eshq

2) There is another lesser known library called [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) which you could look into. It supports both Node.js and Ruby servers and it's based on the [Bayeux Protocol](http://svn.cometd.com/trunk/bayeux/bayeux.html)

Comment: +1 for faye, that looks really interesting and may be a great tool on heroku.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku now has support for WebSockets: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-labs-websockets

Answer (score 0):

While WebSockets isn't currently supported, [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551322/rails-and-socket-io-node-js) you can [use Socket.io on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku), configuring it for long-polling.

Comment: There is nothing on that post that indicates that you would be able to use socket.io on heroku. Furthermore, it is explicitly *not supported*  and if it does work, it is and *unintended behavior* and like all unintended behaviors may be removed without notice.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure that I pasted in the right link at the time but at least it explains how to get Rails and Socket to work together. I've added a link confirming that Heroku supports Socket.io on a node.js stack. Note that you'd probably need/ want to use 2 apps.

Comment: I think this answer is relevant for those who are happy falling back to long-polling.  I've edited it to clarify my assumption of @RobinGower's intent.